# Visual Studio 2012 Missing Azure Mobile Services Table Controller

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, azure-mobile-services

I'm developing the .NET backend for my Azure Mobile Service in VS12 according to [THIS](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-windows-store-dotnet-leaderboard/) guide. If you scroll to the 'Add Web API controllers' section of the guide, you'll notice that a  '**Azure Mobile Services Table Controller**' needs to be added to define a Controller for my Data Objects.

**What should be visible:**

[image]

**What I have in my VS12:**

[image]

I'm missing the Windows Azure Mobile Services and it's Controller Plugins. I installed the Azure Mobile Services extension through NuGet as well, however I still don't see the option when adding a new controller. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you installed the Azure SDK using the Web Platform installer?

Comment: I dont think so. I installed most of the Azure NuGet packages. Do you have a link? @CSharpRocks

Comment: Try googling this: install azure sdk

Comment: @CSharpRocks hey still no luck mate. I installed the VS '12 SDK for .NET. Still doesn't show up. Is it a must to have VS13?